# What's a UK graphic design company's SIC code (Standard Industrial Classification) on Companies House?

Tags: business, freelance

Updating the details for my freelance design company online with UK's Companies House, I was asked to enter its SIC code (Standard Industrial Classification).

Normally this would be:

> SIC Code 7336 - Commercial Art and Graphic Design

...but this option doesn't exist in whatever list the UK uses, which only has:

> - 73110   Advertising agencies
> - 73120   Media representation services
> - 73200   Market research and public opinion polling

Searching found nothing graphic design related on the official lookup resource, http://resources.companieshouse.gov.uk/sic/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to SICSupport.co.uk](http://siccodesupport.co.uk/sic-division.php?division=74) which is a searchable version of the official PDF, it's:

> ### **74.10 Specialised design activities**
>
> This class includes:
>
> - fashion design related to textiles, wearing apparel, shoes, jewellery, furniture and other interior decoration and other fashion goods as well as other personal or household goods
> - industrial design, i.e. creating and developing designs and specifications that optimise the use, value and appearance of products, including the determination of the materials, mechanism, shape, colour and surface finishes of the product, taking into consideration human characteristics and needs, safety, market appeal in  distribution, use and maintenance
> - **activities of graphic designers**
>
> This class **excludes**: 
>   - **design and programming of web pages, see 62.01**

Not best pleased that we're an afterthought in an "other" category...

Web design is pushed over to [62 - Computer programming, consultancy and related activities](http://siccodesupport.co.uk/sic-division.php?division=62), where it's not at all clear but looks like it should come under "62.01/2 Business and domestic software development", which didn't appear to be an option for me, and could come under "62.02 Computer consultancy activities"